# Alinhar verticalmente ao centro itens do rodapé

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando alinhar verticalmente ao centro, itens do meu rodapé, só que pela imagem ocupar um `height` maior fica desalinhado, Como resolver?

```html
<footer class="panel-group panel-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="text-muted text-center"><b>Entre em contato:</b><br />(99) 99999-9999</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="text-muted text-center"><b>Endereço:</b> <br /> Rua tal , 123<br /> Bairro - Cidade - Estado</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-muted text-center col-md-4">
                <img height="120" src="~/Styles/logo-rodape.jpg" alt="logo" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted text-center copyright">© Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes resolver a questão declarando uma altura para as colunas da primeira linha do teu rodapé e depois com um pouco de CSS e a ajuda da propriedade [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), alinhar verticalmente os parágrafos:

```css
.panel-footer .cell{
  height:120px;                 /* mesma altura da imagem */
}
.panel-footer p{
  position: relative;           /* relativo para não sair do seu local com a próxima declaração */
  top: 50%;                     /* empurrar para iniciar ao meio do seu contentor */
  transform: translateY(-50%);  /* puxar a distancia equivalente a metade da sua altura */
}
```

## Exemplo

```css
.panel-footer .cell{
  height:120px;
}
.panel-footer p{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="panel-group panel-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 cell">
                    <p class="text-muted text-center"><b>Entre em contato:</b><br />(99) 99999-9999</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 cell">
                    <p class="text-muted text-center"><b>Endereço:</b> <br /> Rua tal , 123<br /> Bairro - Cidade - Estado</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-muted text-center col-xs-4 cell">
                    <img height="120" src="~/Styles/logo-rodape.jpg" alt="logo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p class="text-muted text-center copyright">© Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-cell` e `vertical-align: middle`